# Identify duplicates based on combination in 2 tables C#

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable

I have 2 data tables.

**Table 1**

```
 User     Dept
  X        HR
  Z        HR
  Z       Admin
  Z       Corp
  B       Admin
```

**Table 2**

```
 User     Dept
  Q       Corp
  Z       Admin
```

Table 1 is bind to a grid on `page_Load`. Now on binding Table 2 to grid on a button click. I don't want Users which are already available in table 1 to be part of table 2.

For ex. User Z having Dept as Admin, is available in both table.

If dept is different then it is allow in table 2, but not when User with same Dept is available.

What is the best and fastest way to check if any combination is present in table 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a left outer join : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add("User", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Dept", typeof(string));
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "X", "HR" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Z", "HR" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Z", "Admin" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Z", "Corp" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "B", "Admin" });

            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.Add("User", typeof(string));
            dt2.Columns.Add("Dept", typeof(string));
            dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Q", "Corp" });
            dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Z", "Admin" });

            var groups =
                from emp2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                join emp1 in dt1.AsEnumerable() on new { user = emp2.Field<string>("User"), dept = emp2.Field<string>("Dept") } equals new { user = emp1.Field<string>("User"), dept = emp1.Field<string>("Dept") } into ps
                from emp1 in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new { emp1 = emp1, emp2 = emp2 };

            DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
            dt3.Columns.Add("User", typeof(string));
            dt3.Columns.Add("Dept", typeof(string));
            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                if (group.emp1 == null)
                {
                    dt3.Rows.Add(group.emp2.ItemArray);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With the given ex it works. but if I change the values at dt1 This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Table in example updated for which your code is not working